# ggplot2 merge dataframes and plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes, one of UK Postcodes and one of Long Lat coordinates, how can I merge the two, and then plot only the matched Postcodes coordinates on my map?.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
   install.packages("ggmap")
    install.packages("ggplot2")

    library(ggmap)
    library(ggplot2)

    #getpostcodes & longlat for UK
    postcodes <- read.csv(file.choose())
    lonlat <-read.csv(file.choose())

    mapfilter = combine the above to files ?

    #uk map
    map.bbox = c(left = -6.5, bottom = 49.5, right = 2, top = 58)

    map.uk <- get_stamenmap(bb = map.bbox, zoom=calc_zoom(map.bbox), maptype="toner-lite")
    ggmap(map.uk)

    #plot the merged file from above
   ggmap(map.uk)+geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), data = data,
                                                alpha = .5, color="darkred", size = 5)                                





    postcodes dataframe  - For some reason the Postcodes are bringing in 3 variables, despite the fact the CSV has only one column of data. 

        ZIP_CODE     X     X.1
    1   SP8 4HX      NA    NA
    2   S63 0JY      NA    NA
    3   WS9 8AN      NA    NA
    ...3700 rows

    lonlat dataframe
        id   postcode    latitude    longtitude
    1   1    AB10 1XG    57.14417    -2.114848
    2   2    AB10 6RN    57.13788    -2.121487
    3   3    AB10 7JB    57.12427    -2.127190
    ....1762397 rows
```

Comment: Could you edit your question deleting image data and replacing it with `dput(head(data,n))` where n is the number of rows you find suitable for reproducibility?

Comment: You can merge using `dplyr` join commands. e.g. `mapfilter <- dplyr::inner_join(postcodes, lonlat, by = c("ZIP_CODE" = "postcode")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for joining which I think is your problem:

```
library(data.table)

dt.1 <- data.table(id = 1:10,
                   x1 = LETTERS[1:10])

dt.1

    id x1
 1:  1  A
 2:  2  B
 3:  3  C
 4:  4  D
 5:  5  E
 6:  6  F
 7:  7  G
 8:  8  H
 9:  9  I
10: 10  J

dt.2 <- data.table(id = seq(from = 2, to = 20, by = 2),
                   lat = seq(from = -5, to = -12.5, length.out = 10),
                   lng = seq(from = 3, to = 4.3, length.out = 10))

dt.2

    id        lat      lng
 1:  2  -5.000000 3.000000
 2:  4  -5.833333 3.144444
 3:  6  -6.666667 3.288889
 4:  8  -7.500000 3.433333
 5: 10  -8.333333 3.577778
 6: 12  -9.166667 3.722222
 7: 14 -10.000000 3.866667
 8: 16 -10.833333 4.011111
 9: 18 -11.666667 4.155556
10: 20 -12.500000 4.300000

setkey(dt.1, id)
setkey(dt.2, id)

dt.merge <- dt.1[dt.2]

dt.merge

    id   x1        lat      lng
 1:  2    B  -5.000000 3.000000
 2:  4    D  -5.833333 3.144444
 3:  6    F  -6.666667 3.288889
 4:  8    H  -7.500000 3.433333
 5: 10    J  -8.333333 3.577778
 6: 12 <NA>  -9.166667 3.722222
 7: 14 <NA> -10.000000 3.866667
 8: 16 <NA> -10.833333 4.011111
 9: 18 <NA> -11.666667 4.155556
10: 20 <NA> -12.500000 4.300000

dt.merge[complete.cases(dt.merge)]

   id x1       lat      lng
1:  2  B -5.000000 3.000000
2:  4  D -5.833333 3.144444
3:  6  F -6.666667 3.288889
4:  8  H -7.500000 3.433333
5: 10  J -8.333333 3.577778
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help.